# Проверить является ли введеное слово анаграммой?

Tags: c++, строки

Я вот написал код, и не понимаю почему мне ошибку выдает, я сам новичок в с++. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int a = 20;
    string S1[a];
    string S2[a];
    int ok = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;

    while (S1[j] != S1.size()) {
        count1++;
        j++;
    }
    while (S2[j] != S2.size()) {
        count2++;
        j++;
    }
    int length1 = count1;
    int length2 = count2;

    for (int i = 0; i < length1 && j < length2; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < length1 && j < length2; j++)
        {
            if (S1[i] != S2[j])
                ok = 1;
            cout << "NO";
            break;
        }


    }
    if (ok == 0) {
        cout << "YES";
    }
}
```

Comment: Где ввод слова или слов?

Comment: `string S1[a];` - это - объявление *массива* строк. У массива нет функции-члена `size()`. Еще - для проверки анаграммности вам нужно отсортировать буквы строк (типа, "строка" должно превратиться в "акорст") и спавнить две отсортированные таким образом строки.

Comment: @Harry - отличное замечание, тоже хотел написать про сравнение отсортированных наборов символов